# Turning vanilla JavaScript into jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Noob here. I am currently in a development bootcamp (some of you may not like these types of things) and am learning a lot in a fast paced environment!

Anyways, I have written this code which is fully functional, however my professor told me to rewrite this using jQuery (solely for teaching purpose, individual bias on which practice is better is unnecessary). I was hoping someone here could help me write some code that functions the exact same way as mine posted below, except using jQuery instead of vanilla JavaScript as I am having some trouble. Thanks in advance!

```js
electa.page.populateStates = function (array) {
    var array = [
        { "id":  1, "countryCode": "NA", "stateCode": "NA", "regionName": ""        },
        { "id":  2, "countryCode": "AK", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Alaska"  }, 
        { "id":  3, "countryCode": "AL", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Alabama" },
        { "id": 82, "countryCode": "WY", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Wyoming" }
    ];
    var selectList = document.getElementById( 'location.state' );
    for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        var option = document.createElement( "option" );
        option.setAttribute( "value", array[ i ].id );
        option.text = array[ i ].regionName;
        selectList.appendChild( option );
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what trouble are you having?  Are you unsure how to select an element using jQuery?  How to create an element using jQuery? Or how to add it to the DOM?

Comment: If it's for learning purposes, what good will it do if we do it for you?

Comment: JavaScript and Java are not the same

Comment: This isn't a coding service. Ask a specific question.

Comment: @APAD1 I've attempted several things none have which have been successful. I'm a visual learner so once I see a good example and implement it once, I will most likely have learned a good deal and not have to ask this question again.

Comment: @self Thanks for pointing that out to me, I'll look into the differences

Comment: @Celeo Thanks for the downvotes. UNNECCESSARY. I am just looking to learn

Comment: @DanielH I think what Celeo meant to say was "Please try to rephrase your question in a way that addresses your primary concern: to learn jQuery by comparison to given javascript example." In your question, you ask us to "help you write some code" which may have prompted his response.

Comment: @Growler hopefully you are correct, it's just discouraging when I know I have a lot to learn and use this site frequently to do so.. And I rarely post questions as I realize I am not high level at all yet so I try to refrain from posting questions seen as simple. Then when I finally decide this is a legitimate question and ask within 10 mins I have two comments basically saying "f*ck off"

Comment: A good question is one which shows that you have at least made some effort to solve the problem yourself. The issue is not that you posted a beginner question(plenty of those on SO with no downvotes). The issue is that you posted a question without doing any of the legwork beforehand(or at least you didn't show us that you did).

Comment: @APAD1 understood, next time I will try to show my legwork (failing code) which there was plenty of... Which was actually the reason I left it out... I tried several different code paths, I probably should have posted my most recent. Apologies

Comment: @DanielH Don't beat yourself up. You've just learned a valuable lesson which is to ALWAYS lead with your own attempt when asking for help.  I had to learn this too.  It's a tough lesson since people aren't terribly nice in pointing it out, but you've got it now and I have no doubt you will be incredibly successful as a developer.  Good luck!

Comment: @BurkeHolland I appreciate the advice! Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a rough approach; I've not tested it, but it should provide a solid basis for understanding the same solution with jQuery playing a larger role. Read the comments; don't short-change yourself. If you'd like to be a solid programmer, make a habit of learning from every sample of code you come across.

```
// We'll still assign our function to the populateStates property the same way
// By naming the parameter `array`, I assume you expect an array to be passed in
electa.page.populateStates = function ( array ) {
    // If an array was passed in, we'll use it, otherwise, we'll provide our own
    // If the left-side of || is evaluated falsey, the right-side will be used instead
    var array = array || [ { "id": 1, "regionName": "" } ];
    // We'll need to locate our select element via a selector
    // We escape the period so jQuery doesn't look for something with a "state" class
    var selectList = $("#location\.state");
    // We can leverage jQuery's $.each method to loop over arrays
    // Modern browsers have functionality to do this on their own
    // See Array.prototype.forEach for instance
    $.each( array, function iteration ( index, obj ) {
        // This creates a new <option> element, and sets value/text accordingly
        // jQuery's $ function does many different things. Get familiar with it.
        $("<option></option>", {
            value: obj.id,
            text: obj.regionName
        // We can call the $.fn.appendTo method directly off the new <option>
        }).appendTo( selectList );
    });
};
```

#### Read Further:

- [The jQuery/$ function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)
- [jQuery.each() in the API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)
- [jQuery's HTML/Attributes Signature](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes)
- [Array.prototype.forEach on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff679980(v=vs.94).aspx)

Comment: Nice summary of differences, helpful for me too!

Comment: Thanks a ton for this. As @Growler mentioned this is extremely helpful. I would upvote but I don't have the ability to yet as my reputation is only 6 as people feel the need to take sh*t on jr developers less experienced programmers. I am going to accept Mathieu Labrie Parent's answer as it is more specific to what I was looking for (that may be my questions fault). But again, thanks a bunch!

Comment: That was really nice of you to do that Jonathan, thanks a ton. It is nice to know there are people out there who are willing to help others solely due to the goodness of their heart! Completely unexpected and appreciated greatly! Hopefully one day our paths will cross again and I will be a much more experienced developer than I am currently!

Answer (score 2):

The best thing I can do is provide jQuery docs for you to read yourself:

- Read jQuery basics and why it is helpful: [Essential jQuery start](http://learn.jquery.com/)
- Understanding jQuery and Non jQuery objects: [Iterating over jQuery and Non jQuery objects](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/)

Some basics pertaining to your JavaScript post:

**[Loops](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):**

JavaScript  `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {`

jQuery: `$.each(array, function (index, properties) {`

**[Arrays in jQuery docs](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/arrays/):**

There isn't a need for a jQuery array wrapper

**[Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):**

JavaScript: `var selectList = document.getElementById('location.state')`

jQuery: Select the element using `$('#hashtagForIDs')` or, `$('.periodForClasses')`, rather than `document.getElementById()`

**[Appending](http://api.jquery.com/append/):**

JavaScript: `selectList.appendChild(option);`

jQuery: use that selector described above, `$("select element to append to").append(what you want to append);`,

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this.

```
electa.page.populateStates = function (array) {
    var array = [ {"id":1, "countryCode":"NA", "stateCode":"NA", "regionName":""}, { "id": 2, "countryCode": "AK ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Alaska" }, { "id": 3, "countryCode": "AL ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Alabama" }, { "id": 4, "countryCode": "AR ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Arkansas" }, { "id": 6, "countryCode": "AZ ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Arizona" }, { "id": 9, "countryCode": "CA ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "California" }, { "id": 10, "countryCode": "CO ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Colorado" }, { "id": 11, "countryCode": "CT ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Connecticut" }, { "id": 12, "countryCode": "DC ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "District of Columbia" }, { "id": 13, "countryCode": "DE ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Delaware" }, { "id": 15, "countryCode": "FL ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Florida" }, { "id": 17, "countryCode": "GA ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Georgia" }, { "id": 18, "countryCode": "GU ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Guam" }, { "id": 21, "countryCode": "HI ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Hawaii" }, { "id": 22, "countryCode": "IA ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Iowa" }, { "id": 23, "countryCode": "ID ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Idaho" }, { "id": 24, "countryCode": "IL ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Illinois" }, { "id": 25, "countryCode": "IN ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Indiana" }, { "id": 26, "countryCode": "KS ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Kansas" }, { "id": 27, "countryCode": "KY ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Kentucky" }, { "id": 28, "countryCode": "LA ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Louisiana" }, { "id": 30, "countryCode": "MA ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Massachusetts" }, { "id": 32, "countryCode": "MD ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Maryland" }, { "id": 33, "countryCode": "ME ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Maine" }, { "id": 35, "countryCode": "MI ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Michigan" }, { "id": 36, "countryCode": "MN ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Minnesota" }, { "id": 37, "countryCode": "MO ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Missouri" }, { "id": 39, "countryCode": "MS ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Mississippi" }, { "id": 40, "countryCode": "MT ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Montana" }, { "id": 42, "countryCode": "NC ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "North Carolina" }, { "id": 43, "countryCode": "ND ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "North Dakota" }, { "id": 44, "countryCode": "NE ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Nebraska" }, { "id": 46, "countryCode": "NH ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "New Hampshire" }, { "id": 47, "countryCode": "NJ ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "New Jersey" }, { "id": 48, "countryCode": "NM ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "New Mexico" }, { "id": 52, "countryCode": "NV ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Nevada" }, { "id": 54, "countryCode": "NY ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "New York" }, { "id": 55, "countryCode": "OH ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Ohio" }, { "id": 56, "countryCode": "OK ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Oklahoma" }, { "id": 58, "countryCode": "OR ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Oregon" }, { "id": 59, "countryCode": "PA ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Pennsylvania" }, { "id": 61, "countryCode": "PR ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Puerto Rico" }, { "id": 65, "countryCode": "RI ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Rhode Island" }, { "id": 67, "countryCode": "SC ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "South Carolina" }, { "id": 68, "countryCode": "SD ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "South Dakota" }, { "id": 72, "countryCode": "TN ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Tennessee" }, { "id": 73, "countryCode": "TX ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Texas" }, { "id": 74, "countryCode": "UT ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Utah" }, { "id": 75, "countryCode": "VA ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Virginia" }, { "id": 78, "countryCode": "VT ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Vermont" }, { "id": 79, "countryCode": "WA ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Washington" }, { "id": 80, "countryCode": "WI ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Wisconsin" }, { "id": 81, "countryCode": "WV ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "West Virginia" }, { "id": 82, "countryCode": "WY ", "stateCode": "US", "regionName": "Wyoming" }]

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        $('#location.state').append("<option value='" + array[i].id + "' >" + array[i].regionName + "</option>");
    }

}
```